# Problems teaching introductory logic. Is this a statement? "If x is an integer, then..."

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Consider the claim, "If $x$ is an integer, then $x^3>0$". Is this a statement?

My text defines a statement as "a declarative sentence which is true or false, but not both."

At first it seemed clear to me that the claim was a false statement. But I imagine a skeptical student saying that the sentence is not a statement because it is sometimes true and sometimes false, depending on the value of $x$. How would you respond?

Is "$x$ is an integer" a statement? It only has a truth value if we set a value for $x$. I am confusing myself. Help?

Comment: A statement is not allowed to have free variables (in this case $x$).  The problem is that in natural language one might take this sentence to have an implied quantifier, so that it means the same as "For every integer $x$, $x^3 > 0$".

Comment: I guess OP is teaching some high school levels students, to whom it's not very trivial to explain bound and free variables. Answers in a less jargonized manner might be more helpful.

Comment: @CaveJohnson The answers are directed at the OP, not the OP's students, and we're assuming that the OP does understand the basic concepts like "universal quantifier" etc. (Note that the OP isn't asking how to explain something.)

Comment: Implicit in natural language is: For all $x$, if $x$ is an integer then $x^3 > 0$. This is false since $-1$ is an integer and $(-1)^3 < 0$. So, we have a a false statement. In a formal proof (not in natural language), whether a formula is a statement or not is not an important distinction.

Answer (score 13):

This gets into a bit of a murky situation, actually. Let's start with a simpler claim: the expression "If $x$ is an integer, then $x^3>3$" is not a *sentence*, but rather a *formula* - the issue being the free variable $x$.

This brings us to a subtle point: the difference between a formula and its **universal closure**. Outside of logic, "If $x$ is an integer, then $x^3>3$" would often be treated as an abbreviation for "For all $x$, if $x$ is an integer then $x^3>3$" (the latter is the *universal closure* of the former: we take the original formula and add "for all"s to the beginning to account for all the free variables). However, within logic there are actually very good reasons (which I won't go into here) to distinguish between a formula and its universal closure, and in particular to be very careful about natural-language conventions like implicit universal quantifiers. This even extends to formulas like "$x=x$," which are tautologically true regardless of what value one assigns to $x$; within logic, "$x=x$" is a formula but not a sentence.

Because of formulas like "$x=x$," where we have a free variable but it's somehow not *importantly* free, I find language like "a statement is "a declarative sentence which is true or false, but not both"" to be quite confusing. For example, if within this context we say that "$x=x$" is a statement since it's obviously true regardless of what $x$ is, then the Boolean combination of two non-statements could be a statement: "$x>0$" and "$x<0$" are both of indeterminate truth value, but "$x>0$ and $x<0$" is false regardless of what value we assign to $x$. By contrast, the notions of *well-formed formula* and *sentence* are perfectly rigorous and easy to work with, and to my mind one of the major points of logic is that it's valuable to shift away from natural-language reasoning about truth and towards more rigorous (if limited and less intuitive) grounds.

---

So what's the answer to your question? Well, I would say that the expression is not a statement. One might disagree and say that when it comes to evaluating the truth of a formula, we implicitly choose to work with its universal closure instead, but I think this is problematic for a number of reasons. Because of this, my advice to you personally is to pick a convention and stick to it (but first read the book carefully and tell if *it is already* making such an implicit convention!). After all, **once a convention is settled on** everything will work itself out well (even if the "wrong" convention is chosen), but there may be some disagreement over what the convention should be.

Comment: In non-mathematical contexts the universal closure is often implicitly assumed to be part of the sentence.  E.g. if you said " If a man is an NHL (National Hockey League) player  then he earns over \$100K/yr.", most people would consider this to mean "For all men, if a man is an NHL player then...(etc.)."  And would also assume that an existential quantifier is included somewhere, as they don't expect you  would say it if you weren't sure that  the NHL has more than $0$ players............+1

Answer (score 5):

"If x is an integer, ..." means "For all integers x, ..." The universal quantifier is hidden here, but this a convention of mathematical English. The student needs to understand this point- it's very important.

Comment: I personally disagree; I think we need to distinguish between formulas and their universal closures. In this case I would say the expression is not a statement.

Comment: Context matters: a universal quantifier might be considered implicit when the sentence is clearly talking about an arbitrary $x$, but it *may* be refering to a particular one.  Since we don't have the context, we cannot simply presume it.

Comment: @GrahamKemp And the recognition of the importance of that context is why we generally make this distinction in logic.

Comment: As much as you might dislike this construction, it's commonly enough used in mathematical writing that students should have it explained to them.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I certainly agree that it's important for students to be aware of the convention, but I think they also need to be aware of why it's problematic (and to internalize that within logic we have to be more precise).

Comment: If $x$ in the sentence is referring to a particular $x$ then again have a statement.

Comment: Where do you get the strange notion that "if $x$ is an integer ..." means "for all integers $x$, ..."? I have never encountered mathematical writing where "if" works as a variable-binding construct. Please provide some examples,

Comment: See the discussion on page 623 and following of A Handbook of Mathematical Discourse, by Charles Wells, which cites examples.    http://case.edu/artsci/math/wells/pub/pdf/hyperhbk.pdf

Comment: @BrianBorchers Indeed and none of those examples justifies a reading of a conditional as a universal quantification, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3):

This is depends on the convention, but without context I would say that $(x\in S)\implies(P(x))$ is not a statement!

A statement has only bound variable, in some cases the language you are talking can imply some quantifier but we have to be precise, try to write it formally, if $x$ is free then it is not a statement

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

If you like programming, formulate your problem like this:

```
IsPosCube(x) := x^3 > 0
NumCheck(x) := if IsInt(x) then IsPosCube(x) else True
```

Which I think is nice, because by making functions you can see that your expressions can't be evaluated without variable assignments, making them formulas and not statements. However, `NumCheck(-3)` is easily seen to be a false statement. But interestingly, `NumCheck(3.3)` is a true statement! This is why your formula isn't equivalent to the statement "The cube of any integer is positive."

Comment: Is the 'if ... then' of the OP equivalent to an "if-then-else" construct?  That seems doubtful.

Comment: Yes, when evaluated!